# Left Outer Join with Multiple Conditions - Null Exception

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

I am trying to create a query that shows efficiencies by department and then month.  I need every month to be included even if there is no data for that month.

The first query to get the data works fine as does the simple query to get the last twelve months.

However, when I try to left outer join them, I get a null exception, even though I am handling every field being null in the select new.

I can't see where I am going wrong...

```
var departmentMonthlyEfficiences =
    (from o in operations
     join contract in contracts on o.Contract equals contract.Sequence.ToString()
     group o by new { o.Department, o.LastWorkDate.Year, o.LastWorkDate.Month} into dm
     where dm.Sum(o => o.ActualHours) > 0
     select new { Department = dm.Key.Department, Year = dm.Key.Year, Month = dm.Key.Month, Efficiency = dm.Sum(o => o.PlannedHours) / dm.Sum(o => o.ActualHours) });

var now = DateTime.Now;
var months = Enumerable.Range(-12, 12)
    .Select(x => new { 
        Year = now.AddMonths(x).Year, 
        Month = now.AddMonths(x).Month });

var departmentAllMonthlyEfficiences = (
      from m in months
      join deptMonth in departmentMonthlyEfficiences on new { Month = m.Month, Year = m.Month } equals new { Month = deptMonth.Month, Year = deptMonth.Year } into deptsWithAllMonths
      from deptAllMonth in deptsWithAllMonths.DefaultIfEmpty()

      select new { 
        Department= deptAllMonth.Department == null ? "empty": deptAllMonth.Department, 
        Year=m.Year == null ? 2019: m.Year, 
        Month=m.Month == null ? 12:m.Month, 
        Efficiency=deptAllMonth.Efficiency == null ? 0: deptAllMonth.Efficiency  
      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `join` (normally an inner join) together with extension method `DefaultIfEmpty` are emulating in LINQ an outer join (and LINQ-to-Entities will make it so when the actual SQL is generated). `DefaultIfEmpty` says that — should `deptsWithAllMonths` be an empty set — to return a set containing a single, default, object instead ... the default object for the anonymous type returned from the first query is `null`:

```
select new
{
    Department = deptAllMonth == null || deptAllMonth.Department == null
                   ? "empty"
                   : deptAllMonth.Department,
    Year = m.Year,
    Month = m.Month,
    Efficiency = deptAllMonth == null || deptAllMonth.Efficiency == null
                   ? 0
                   : deptAllMonth.Efficiency
}
```

However, you should instead consider this advice: [**Navigation Properties are More Readable than Joins**](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). One of the important aspects of using Navigation Properties applies in the case of your question:

> both LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities coalesce nulls.